# Saving child record is not working in doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony 2 with Doctrine 2. I have 2 entities User and Email. User can have many Emails. Relation is set up like this.

```
class User
{
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserEmail", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
   */
   protected $emails;
}

class UserEmail
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="user_emails")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected $user;
}
```

In controller I am doing something like this.

```
$user = new User();
$email = new UserEmail();
$user->getEmails()->add($email);
$user->setLocked(false)->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());

$form = $this->createForm(new RegisterUser(), $user, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('register'),
));

$form->handleRequest($request);

if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $registration = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($registration);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

However I am getting error like this.

```
 An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user_emails (id, user_id, email, is_verified, token, is_primary, data, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["2abbe629-264d-471b-a9dd-4a471657e61c", null, "re@re.com", null, null, null, null, null, null]:

 SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "user_id" violates  not-null constraint
 DETAIL: Failing row contains (2abbe629-264d-471b-a9dd-4a471657e61c, null, re@re.com, null, null, null, null, null, null).
 500 Internal Server Error - DBALException
 1 linked Exception:

 PDOException
```

Can somebody please help me. I am new to Symfony 2 world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this issue. I am posting the solution so that others can benefit from it.

I had to set up two way relationship like this.

```
$user = new User();
$email = new UserEmail();
$user->getEmails()->add($email);
$email->setUser($user);
```

Then I had to enable cascade validation like this for validation. (RegisterUser.php)

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Django\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User',
        'cascade_validation' => true //This is cascades the validation
    ));
}
```

Now, for validation of unique entity I had to do this since email had to be unique.

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * UserEmail
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="dj_user_emails")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Django\Bundle\UserBundle\Repository\UserEmail")
 * @UniqueEntity("email", message="email_in_use")
 */
 class UserEmail
 {
   /**
    * @var string Email
    *
    * @Assert\NotBlank()
    * @Assert\Email()
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=128, unique=true)
    */
    private $email;
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `inversedBy` annotation on the `UserEmail`class like this:

```
class UserEmail
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="emails")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected $user;
}
```

Hope this help